# vim: substitute characters from backreference

Tags: regex, vim, backreference

I want to do the following subtitutions in vim: I have a string (with spaces eventually) and a number at the end of the line. I want to create a C `#define` with that string in uppercase + a prefix + underscores, the number (in hex) and finally the original string as a comment.

For example, from:

```
hw version 0
```

to:

```
#define MY_HW_VERSION (0x00) // hw version
```

So far, I wrote the following regex:

```
s/^\(.*\) \(\d\+\)$/#define MY_\U\1\E (0x0\2)\/\/ \1/
```

which gives

```
#define MY_HW VERSION (0x00) // hw version
```

- uppercase: OK (use `\U` to start uppercasing and `\E` to end it)
- prefix: OK
- number: OK (hex might be an issue, but that is not the purpose of my question)
- comment: OK (reuse back-reference `\1`)

But can you see the space left? `MY_HW VERSION` instead of `MY_HW_VERSION`...

So I'd like to make a substitution **in the back-reference** `\1` like `\1:s/\s/_/g`. Is it possible at all? How to do it?

Thanks!

Comment: would not be easier to use separated groups for "hw" and "version" ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this would be the one-line `:s` cmd,  works for your example: (I break it into multi-lines, just for better reading)

```
s@\v(.*) (\d+)@
\='#define MY_'
.toupper(substitute(submatch(1),' ','_','g'))
.' (0x0'.submatch(2).') //'.submatch(1)@
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a little on `\v`, `\=` and the`.` (dots) you use? Thanks for your fast answer.

Comment: You beat me this time, even though I used the shorter `tr()` instead of `substitute()`

Comment: `:h magic` for `\v`, `:h sub-replace-expression` for `\=` and `dot` is for string concatenation. in short: `'a'.'b' -> 'ab'` @CJlano

Comment: @IngoKarkat yes, `tr()` is enough for this example. I didn't think of it.  I guess `\v` helped me a little? ;)

Answer (score 4):

If it's a maximum of two words, you can add additional capture groups:

```
s/^\(\S\+\) \(\S\+\) \(\d\+\)$/#define MY_\U\1_\2\E (0x0\3)\/\/ \1/
```

For full flexibility, you can use `:help sub-replace-expression`; you then need to use string concatenation and Vimscript functions like `toupper()` instead of `\U`:

```
s@^\(.*\) \(\d\+\)$@\='#define MY_' . toupper(tr(submatch(1), ' ', '_')) . '(0x0' . submatch(2) . ') //' . submatch(1)@
```